# How can I replace ; with , in an imported excel file and to delete "

Tags: list-manipulation, import, excel

I want to import an excel `.csv` file and `ListPlot` the data.

```
file = Import["Desktop/PP_1039.CSV", "Data"]
```

But I get this data  :

```
(*{{"0.0472;120.9091"}, {"0.0454;113.0303"}, {"0.0441;106.6667"},
  {"0.0442;106.6667"}, {"0.0437;103.3333"}, {"0.0425;95.1515"}, 
  {"0.0409;83.6364"}, {"0.0387;72.7273"}, {"0.0354;59.697"}, 
 {"0.0317;45.7576"}, {"0.0275;34.8485"}, {"0.0234;24.8485"}, 
 {"0.0155;12.1212"}, {"0.0115;6.6667"}, {"0.0072;2.7273"},    
 {"0.0031;2.1212"}}  *)
```

So I'd like to delete the `"` and to replace `;` with `,`

Comment: `StringReplace`?

Comment: Just be aware that `ToExpression` (i.e. the answer you accepted) will not handle all number formats that are allowed (and often present) in CSV files, such as `123.4e5`.

Comment: You could try importing the file via `ReadList[file, Expression]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[file], ";" -> ","]]
```

> {{0.0472, 120.9091}, {0.0454, 113.0303}, {0.0441, 106.6667}, {0.0442, 
>     106.6667}, {0.0437, 103.3333}, {0.0425, 95.1515}, {0.0409, 
>     83.6364}, {0.0387, 72.7273}, {0.0354, 59.697}, {0.0317, 
>     45.7576}, {0.0275, 34.8485}, {0.0234, 24.8485}, {0.0155, 
>     12.1212}, {0.0115, 6.6667}, {0.0072, 2.7273}, {0.0031, 2.1212}}

Answer (score 11):

Import as [Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) instead of CSV, and set the `"FieldSeparators"` option.

```
ImportString[
 "1;2
 3;4", 
 "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {";"}]

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

"Table" is a generalization of CSV, TSV, etc. where you can customize the delimiters and separators.

Answer (score 4):

```
ToExpression[file /. {a_String} :> StringSplit[a, ";"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Method One:
1) Caution: Make a copy of your original file and then proceed. Just in case it doesn't work. :)
2) Select all the contents in which you need to make the changes.
3) Use "Replace" command to replace whatever with whatever you want. (Replace " with ***blank space*** and ; with ,)
4) That it.

Method Two:
1) Caution: Make a copy of your original file and then proceed. Just in case it doesn't work. :)
2) Copy all the contents in Word. It will most probably be imported as a table.
3) Select all the contents in which you need to make the changes.
4) Use "Replace" command to replace whatever with whatever you want. **(**Replace " with ***blank space*** and ; with ,**)**
5) Select all the contents from word that are in table and paste it in Excel again.

Comment: In what sense is this solution related to _Mathematica_?